# Column to identify duplicates

Tags: sql

I've got a table of data, and am trying to identify where duplicate values exist. I can write a query which only returns duplicates, but I'm after a query to return all records, and add a 'Count' column to show how many times it occurs

For example,

```
ID  Name   Surname  Email
1   Adam   Smith    a.smith@domain.com
2   Bob    Clark    b.clark@domain.com
3   Andy   Smith    a.smith@domain.com
```

And I want a query to return:

```
ID  Name   Surname  Email               Count
1   Adam   Smith    a.smith@domain.com  2
2   Bob    Clark    b.clark@domain.com  1
3   Andy   Smith    a.smith@domain.com  2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you consider a duplicate to be a matching email, then this one will work:

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.surname, T.email, sub.count
FROM T
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM T
GROUP BY email) sub
ON T.email = sub.email
```

If you want both surname and email to match to be considered a duplicate, try this:

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.surname, T.email, sub.count
FROM T
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT email, surname, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM T
GROUP BY email, surname) sub
ON T.email = sub.email
AND T.surname = sub.surname
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84c041/2

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.*
      ,B.Count
 From YourTable A
 Join (Select Email,count=count(*) From YourTable Group By EMail) B
   on A.EMail=B.EMail
```

Comment: add some explanation